# Integral with cosines and power or upper bound

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to solve this integral or find its upper bound
$$\int_M^\infty \frac{2}{(t^2 \pi^2 + \epsilon^2)^\beta}\sin(\pi x t)\sin(\pi z t)\mathrm{d}t$$
I got to simplify upstairs as
$$\int_M^\infty \frac{\cos(\pi t(x - z)) - \cos(\pi t(x + z))}{(t^2 \pi^2 + \epsilon^2)^\beta}\mathrm{d}t$$
So now we can solve two simpler integrals, but I'm stuck here.

$M \ge 1$ and it is an integer. $\beta$ is a natural number. $x$ and $z$ are $0 \le x,z \le 1$ and $\epsilon > 0$

Can anybody help me?

Thank you!!

EDIT: I think an upper bound may be 
$$ 2 \int_M^\infty \frac{1}{(t^2 \pi^2 + \epsilon^2)^\beta} \mathrm{d}t$$

This integral gives an hypergeometric: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html

But I need a bound as a function of M. Is it possible to bound/solve this integral?

Comment: What is known about $M$, $\beta$, $\epsilon$ and $z$?

Comment: $ M \geq 1$ and it is an integer.

$\beta$ is a natural number.   

x and z are $ 0 \leq x, z \leq 1$

Comment: I forgot: $\epsilon > 0$ . Thanks!